# Android: Show custom layout in BaseActivity

Tags: android, xml

When app is in foreground, I want to show a layout sliding down from top when a notification received and goes back to top after few seconds. No matter which activity is opened.
I have tried TSnackbar library but it does not fulfill my need.

Comment: I don't want to show notifications in tray but in app which is in foreground.

Comment: > No matter which activity is opened was misleading

Comment: In that case, capture the notifcation `Intent` using a `BroadcastReceiver` and use an `ObjectAnimator` to animate your layout.

Comment: Thanks ALex T. I didn't get exact help. But extracted something useful from your answer.